# Jni передать аргументы в функцию

Tags: java, android, jni

Есть java функция

```
public static String test(String a, Object... args) {

}
```

jni

```
jstring test(JNIEnv *env,char* str,jobject... args){

}
```

jni ругается на jobject... args.Как в jni сделать функцию с неограниченными аргументами?

Answer (score 1):

Данный пример описывает приём параметров типа `String`

```
// Находим указатель на данный метод
mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, class, "test", "(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V");

// Метод на С
static void test(JNIEnv * env, char* str, jobject o, ...) {
  int i = 0;
  int count = 0;
  char * msg[100+1] = {0};  // количество аргументов, максимум 100
  jobjectArray ja;
  va_list list;
  va_start(list, o);
  do {msg[count] = va_arg(list,char *);
  } while(msg[count] !=0 && ++count < 100);
  va_end(list);
  ja = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, count, (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String"), (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, ""));
  for(i=0;i!=count;i++) {
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,ja,i,(*env)->NewStringUTF(env, msg[i]));
  }
  (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, o, mid, ja);
}
```

Пример вызова на C:

```
test(env, "MyName", o, "0", "a", "1", NULL);
```

Comment: Вы уверены что там не просто `jobjectArray` в качестве типа последнего аргумента?

Comment: Если бы было не `varargs`, а `String[]`, то да

Comment: Так varargs в рантайме превращается в массив.